# jquery check for long strings in a textarea

Tags: jquery

I have users typing in incredibly long strings, as below, is there a way in jquery to detect that a string is getting too long so that I can warn the user?

```
<textarea>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</textarea>
```

I'm thinking a keyup that checks the length since the last space (or since the beginning if no spaces)

Comment: why do you want to use jquery? use javascript

Comment: isn't jquery often the simpler quicker solution in most cases?

Comment: Regardless, what you are suggesting is a fine solution Jim.

Comment: by getting too long, do you mean as the user is typing the string?

Comment: javascript is faster in most cases, I don't see any reason to use jquery just to check the string length

Comment: yes the user types it like in the textarea example, i need to tell them a limit of 50 chars or something

Comment: wel it's not as simple as string.length since i need to allow for spaces and the key event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

It checks the string length of word since last space.

```
$('#test').keyup(function() {
    var string = $(this).val();
    var n = $(this).val().lastIndexOf(" ");

    var lastword= string.substring(n+1, string.length);

    if(lastword.length > 10) {
      alert('Too long');        
    }     
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A4V8k/1/)

Comment: Ok, I didn't get the point it's on a word basis. Also, I recommend you  use a buffer on the event so that you only check after a few keys are typed, in that way there will be less side effects on slow computers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
<textarea id="myTA" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
```

then with jQuery :

```
function(){
    $("myTA").change(function(_itm){
        if(_itm.length >= 1000)
            alert("Too long");
        });
}();
```

You should get something with this, try it out...

Comment: thanks but does that detect a string length? It looks like it checks the length of the entire textarea input, I nee to check for a very long string